# Signal is not audible after frequency re-sampling

Tags: signal-analysis, frequency, audio-processing

I'm trying to change the frequency of an audio signal from 22050hz to 500hz. I'm using librosa to read the wav audio and pass the custom sampling rate as 500. Once read, I'm saving it back to audio file. The frequency of the signal has been updated (verified using fft) but the problem is that new signal is inaudible (no sound). 
It works fine (audible) for 8000hz as well as 4000hz. But as soon as I go below 4000, it becomes inaudible.
I've attached the plots for both signals (original: 22050 and modified: 500hz). Each plot shows time domain and frequency domain respectively.
Kindly let me know if I am doing something wrong or missing some DSP basics...[image: [![][1]]][image: [![][2]]]

Comment: Does the original audio file have a sample rate of 500 Hz?

Comment: No. Original files sampling rate is 22050hz.

Comment: Then are you sure you want to pass the audio read function 500 Hz? Shouldn’t you pass it the true sampling rate?

Comment: I am passing it to change the frequency of the audio file. 
I don't know if it's correct but I want to achieve is that I want to modify the frequency of this audio signal from 22050 to 500. Let me know if you have any suggestions.